# How do I add character padding to a string?

Tags: python, string, padding

Okay this is very hard to explain, but i want to add padding to a sentence so that the characters in that sentence are a multiple of n.

however this number '4' has to change to 3 and 5 so it has to work then as well..

anyone know what im talking about?? and how to do it?

Comment: something to do with `izip_longest` is my guess but i'm still trying to understand the question

Comment: yes im so confused as well :/

Comment: actually nvm... i don't think it is that...

Comment: i think i have to add an X on each side of the text starting from the right until it fits the amount of characters needed??

Comment: nvm my bad now i get it.

Comment: I haven't coded a solution yet but you want to be using the `center` method of a string eg. `''.center(width,padding)` to accomplish this task.

Comment: ok thankyou, i will research this :)

Comment: Is this homework or do you want an actual solution, if it is homework you can use the `homework` tag so people just give hints.

Comment: ECNE LIGI VXLA NRET EXSI XMOD EERF XFOX ECIR PXEH T
this is what your encrypt() function returns , here only the last letter is of length 1, rest all are of length=4.
Then I guess padding is required only for the 'T'??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the self commented code below would help you grasp the concept. You just have to do some maths to get the pad characters at either end

Some concept

1. Extra Characters required Padding = len(string) % block_length
2. Total_Pad_Characters = block_length - len(string) % block_length
3. Pad Character's at front = Total_Pad_Characters/2
4. Pad Character's at end   = Total_Pad_Characters - Total_Pad_Characters/2

So here is the code

```
>>> def encrypt(st,length):
    #Reversed the String and replace all Spaces with 'X'
    st = st[::-1].replace(' ','X')
    #Find no of characters to be padded.
    padlength = (length - len(st)%length) % length
    #Pad the Characters at either end
    st = 'X'*(padlength/2)+st+'X'*(padlength-padlength/2)
    #Split it with size length and then join with a single space
    return ' '.join(st[i:i+length] for i in xrange(0,len(st),length))

>>> encrypt('THE PRICE OF FREEDOM IS ETERNAL VIGILENCE', 4) #Your Example
'XECN ELIG IVXL ANRE TEXS IXMO DEER FXFO XECI RPXE HTXX'
>>> encrypt('THE PRICE', 5) # One Extra Character at end for Odd Numbers
'ECIRP XEHTX'
>>> encrypt('THE PRIC', 5) # 1 Pad Characters at either end
'XCIRP XEHTX'
>>> encrypt('THE PRI', 5) # 1 Pad Characters at either end and one Extra for being Odd
'XIRPX EHTXX'
>>> encrypt('THE PR', 5) # 2 Pad Characters at either end
'XXRPX EHTXX'
>>> encrypt('THE P', 5) # No Pad characters required
'PXEHT'
>>> encrypt('THE PRICE OF FREEDOM IS ETERNAL VIGILENCE', 5) #Ashwini's Example
'XXECN ELIGI VXLAN RETEX SIXMO DEERF XFOXE CIRPX EHTXX'
>>>
```

Comment: +1 Your method of calculating the padlength is much better than mine. But why not use the built-in function `center`?

Comment: @jamylak: Ohhh I was too engrossed with the calculation that it skipped my mind. I will change my code

Comment: Actually it appears that `center` doesn't seem to work properly for odd numbers...

Comment: ok so this works :) trying to convert it too my own code and it doesnt, this really infuriates me!! i swear it is exactly the same just different names!! thankyou for this, i will make mine work eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def pad(yourString,blockLength):
    return yourString + ("X" * (blockLength - (len(yourString) % blockLength)))
```

Is your padding function. for end padding. 
If you need center padding use:

```
def centerPad(yourString,blockLength):
    return ("X" * ((blockLength - (len(yourString) % blockLength))/2)) + yourString + ("X" * ((blockLength - (len(yourString) % blockLength))/2))
```

you need to take a harder look at the rest of your code if you want to implement a block cypher.

Comment: what is a block cipher? is it like a decryption? cause i have already done that and it works... or does it have something to do with this -   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting which is what the shell returns when i test it

Comment: a [block cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) is  what it looks like you are trying to do. you are right about the error message. I corrected it.

Comment: From The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters, `Readability counts.`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import math
>>> def encrypt(string, length):
        inverse_string = string.replace(' ','X')[::-1]

        center_width = int(math.ceil(len(inverse_string)/float(length)) * length) # Calculate nearest multiple of length rounded up

        inverse_string = inverse_string.center(center_width,'X')

        create_blocks = ' '.join(inverse_string[i:i+length] for i in xrange(0,len(inverse_string),length))
        return create_blocks

>>> encrypt('THE PRICE OF FREEDOM IS ETERNAL VIGILENCE', 4)
'XECN ELIG IVXL ANRE TEXS IXMO DEER FXFO XECI RPXE HTXX'
```

Comment: for encrypt('THE PRICE OF FREEDOM IS ETERNAL VIGILENCE', 5)
your program returns :

XECNE LIGIV XLANR ETEXS IXMOD EERFX FOXEC IRPXE HTXX
where the 'htxx' is of length 4 which is wrong?

Comment: oh sorry forgot to use the length paramater... my bad i will add that in

Comment: ok that worked.. almost, at leas for that one it does, but it doesnt for uneaven block lengths.. like 1,3 and 5

Comment: @Chaudhary how in the world do you know this?

Comment: Hmm `center` doesn't seem to work for odd numbers, use @Abhijit's method

Comment: @ashkelly what do I know?
please check my solution as well.