# Splitting Text up in python?

Tags: python

Basically i need to write code relating to Pseudo-cryptography, in which I am given a message/text and i need to encrypt it. The process includes:

1. Replacing the spaces between words with an “X”.
2. Reversing the text.
3. Padding out the beginning and end of the text with Xs so that the total number of       characters is a multiple of four
4. Splitting the text up into blocks of four characters.

I have been able to successfully write working code to do the first 3 steps. (See at bottom of question) but i **CANNOT** and am in dire HELP with the last step. So for example if im given this text: 'heyhowareyou' I need the last step to return: 'heyh owar eyou'. So it needs to be split up all in the same string. Could Anyone please **help** me with this? Thank you soo MUCH!!

**Code written so far, that evaluates the first 3 steps:**

```
# Defining function to encrypt the message.
def encrypt(string, block_size):

    # Padding the begining and end of the text with 'X'.
    string_list = list(string)
    string_list.insert(0, 'X')
    string_list.append('X')
    string_list = ''.join(string_list)

    # Reversing the string.
    string_reversed = string_list[::-1]

    # Replacing any spaces with 'X'.
    string_reversed = string_reversed.replace(' ', 'X')
```

**Attempt at writing code for fourth step:**

```
    for index in range(len(string)):
        string_list_1 = list(string_reversed)
        string_list_1.insert(4, ' ')
        string_list_1 = ''.join(string_list_1)

    return string_list_
```

Comment: This question comes up almost daily. Look at some of the questions in the sidebar of this page.

Comment: Rule0: do not write your own encryption algo unless you are absolutely sure about what you are doing. http://diovo.com/2009/02/wrote-your-own-encryption-algorithm-duh/

Comment: @zengr: The OP did refer to it as pseudo-cryptography, so I'm sure they are aware of the distinction.

Comment: How is this question different from [How do I add character padding to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070857/how-do-i-add-character-padding-to-a-string) posted an hour ago?

Comment: Why do you "need" to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
return [ string_reversed[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(string_reversed), 4) ]
```

Comment: This one is very close to what i need. But two problems, since this is a test case (it is for assessment), the result cannot be in a LIST, and cannot be separate strings within a LIST. So what i get from this code is ['heyh', 'owar', 'eyou'] i need it to return, 'heyh owar eyou'.

Is this possible? thank you so much

Comment: Then join it back together again. You obviously already know how to do that. BTW, it isn't polite to ask homework questions without tagging them as such. (Shame on me for not realising.)

Comment: @user1321578 `' '.join(your_list)`

Comment: Of course, thank you.
Oh, I'm sorry, I literally just signed up to this site, I am very much a newb at it, and sorry for not mentioning that it was homework. 

My bad, sorry.